# PHP Conditional rounding of the minutes of a time stamp

Tags: php, function

I need a Function that rounds the minutes of a time stamp to round up the next 15 minutes when the time is 5 minutes above the previous 15 minutes.

01:05:00 = 01:15:00
01:04:00 = 01:00:00
01:20:00 = 01:30:00
01:19:00 = 01:15:00

I have this right now but the flaw is some times it will round down due to the really poor attempt on my part.

```
function roundTime10($timestamp10, $precision10 = 10) {
  $timestamp10 = strtotime($timestamp10);
  $precision10 = 60 * $precision10;
  return date('H:i:s', round($timestamp10 / $precision10) * $precision10);
}
$Billable_Time = roundTime10($Billable_Time);

function roundTime15($timestamp15, $precision15 = 15) {
  $timestamp15 = strtotime($timestamp15);
  $precision15 = 60 * $precision15;
  return date('H:i:s', round($timestamp15 / $precision15) * $precision15);
}
$Billable_Time = roundTime15($Billable_Time);
echo $Billable_Time;
```

could anyone show me a better way to do this or ad to my way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The basic logic for this is "subtract five minutes, divide by 15 to an integer result then add one and multiply by fifteen".

```
01:04:00 = 01:00:00: 4-5 = -1.  -1/15 = -0.xxx (round down to -1).  (-1+1)*15 = 0
01:20:00 = 01:30:00: 20-5 = 15. 15/15 = 1 (round down to 1). (1+1)*15 = 30
01:19:00 = 01:15:00: 19-5 = 14. 14/15 = 0.xxx (round down to 0). (0+1)*15 = 15
```

I don't have a PHP interpreter handy so won't write the code but you need to replace "round($timestamp15 / $precision15) * $precision15" with something that uses the logic above. You'll want to use the PHP floor() as it rounds negatives down while round() rounds towards or away from zero.